# Strange Crash with FckEditor IE and Image Moving

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, crash, fckeditor

We have used FCKEditor for a long time and been very happy with it. Just recently though a new problem has occurred.

If we insert an image into html and save it, then fine. If we then move the image around inside the the text and re-save (i.e. Get the html from the control for saving to a db) then IE crashes (FF does not of course). But if we view the source with Fck's view source button before we save the changes then IE does not crash. Is there some kind of html check which occurs during the view source action which prevents the crash?

Has anyone had this problem and if so do you have a suggestion for a fix (apart from stop using IE of course which I would love to tell all my clients to do......)

Many thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted the stack where the crash occurred.  Don't forget to setup public symbols: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was traced to an misbehaving plugin for FCKEditor and not the editor itself.

Thanks